# How to wrap several nodes within a XML document to a new node using XQuery?

Tags: xml, xquery, marklogic

I want to Wrap multiple nodes (specific nodes) into a **new single node** within my xml document and then want to insert it.

**Example XML Document-**

```
<root>
  <value1>somevalue</value1>
  <value2>somevalue</value2>
  <value3>somevalue</value3>
  <value4>somevalue</value4>
  <value5>Australia</value5>
  <value6>India</value6>
  <value7>USA</value7>
  <value8>somevalue</value8>
  <value9>somevalue</value9>
  <value10>somevalue</value10>
</root>
```

Since my **value5 to value7** are name of the countries, i want to put them at the same father node.
The output need to look like this:

**Output-**

```
<root>
  <value1>somevalue</value1>
  <value2>somevalue</value2>
  <value3>somevalue</value3>
  <value4>somevalue</value4>
  <Country>
    <value5>Australia</value5>
    <value6>India</value6>
    <value7>USA</value7>
  </Country>
  <value8>somevalue</value8>
  <value9>somevalue</value9>
  <value10>somevalue</value10>
</root>
```

Similarly if my other values belong to some other fields/properties then i want to WRAP them in a new single node.

Any Suggestions?

Comment: Is the list of country names you want to use for grouping/wrapping known? Do you only want to group those adjacent elements, like in your example, or would a sequence of  `<value>Australia</value><value>foo</value><value>USA</value>` also wrap as `<Country><value>Australia</value><value>USA</value></Country><value>foo</value>`?

Comment: Yes it is known(elements or country names) and they can be adjacent to each other or cannot be adjacent to each other. In my database i do have more than thousand documents so it is hard to say if these element will be always adjacent to each other.

Comment: For a clear problem description we would need to know whether you only want to wrap adjacent elements with country values or want to simply wrap all elements with country values as the second option seems to be a simple grouping with `group by $is-country := $value = $countries` while the first option is something best done with a `window` clause. As I don't use Marklogic I can't help with replacing that,  other than writing a recursive function that collects the tail of a sequence as long as it finds country values and then wraps them.

Comment: In most of the document i can see the name of the countries are adjacent to each other. But how i should implement this in XQuery without using tumbling window method. Any generic way to do that ? Marklogic do have the API's like `xdmp:node-insert-after/xdmp:node-insert-child` but i am not sure if they will be useful for this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve what you are trying to do in XSLT, using [`xsl:for-each-group`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#element-for-each-group).

If you want to group them when the value is not equal to "somevalue", then you could use `group-adjacent` to test whether the element value is equal to "somevalue" or not, and then wrap those that are not in the `<country>` element.

You can execute an XSLT within your XQuery module in MarkLogic, like this:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
declare variable $doc := document {
<root>
  <value1>somevalue</value1>
  <value2>somevalue</value2>
  <value3>somevalue</value3>
  <value4>somevalue</value4>
  <value5>Australia</value5>
  <value6>India</value6>
  <value7>USA</value7>
  <value8>somevalue</value8>
  <value9>somevalue</value9>
  <value10>somevalue</value10>
</root>
};

declare variable $grouping-xslt :=
  <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="root">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-adjacent=". = 'somevalue'">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()">
                        <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <country>
                            <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
                        </country>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each-group>        
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>;

xdmp:xslt-eval($grouping-xslt, $doc)
```

If you have a known sequence of country names that you would want to group by, then you could do that with `group-by` and test whether the value matches any of the country names:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
declare variable $doc := document {
<root>
  <value1>somevalue</value1>
  <value2>somevalue</value2>
  <value3>somevalue</value3>
  <value4>somevalue</value4>
  <value5>Australia</value5>
  <value6>India</value6>
  <value7>USA</value7>
  <value8>somevalue</value8>
  <value9>somevalue</value9>
  <value10>somevalue</value10>
</root>
};

declare variable $grouping-xslt :=
  <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:param name="countries" />
    <xsl:template match="root">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-by=". = $countries">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()">
                        <country>
                            <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
                        </country>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                         <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each-group>        
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>;

declare variable $params := map:new(map:entry("countries", ("Australia", "India", "USA")));

xdmp:xslt-eval($grouping-xslt, $doc, $params)
```

Comment: @Mads-- Thanks for answering. This looks good to me but i am having one issue. The values which you took inside $params ("Australia","India","USA")- I am not focussed on the values instead i want to have focus on their nodes i.e;("value5","value6","value7"). All these should be wrapped up under my country Element. It doesn't matter what is the value i am having inside these element. It can be any contry name. So how should i modify the code based on that.

Comment: @Shalini, for the adjacent grouping done with XSLT you could change `group-adjacent=". = 'somevalue'"` to `group-adjacent="not(self::value5 | self::value6 | self::value7)"`. If you simply want to wrap all value5, value6, value7 elements then I think you can do that easily in XQuery with `<root>{* except (value5, value6, value7), <countries>{value5, value6, value7}</countries>}</root>`.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Thank you so much- That works well for me. One more doubt i am having is if  my $doc is having root node and inside to it- it is having more nodes and then document structure then how i am suppose to handle it. I mean if my doc looks like `<root><sibling1><sibling2>
  <value1>somevalue</value1>
  <value2>somevalue</value2>
  <value3>somevalue</value3></sibling1></sibling2></root>`

Comment: I am not sure if i confused you by my question- In simpler form what changes i am supposed to make inside `<xsl:template match="root">` if my root node changes and having multiple child inside `root`

Comment: If the root element is variable but you know you want to process the children of the root element then you can use `<xsl:template match="/*">` instead of `<xsl:template match="root">`. If you don't want to process the children of the root element but the children of the element named `sibling2` then you would write a template `<xsl:template match="sibling2">` with the grouping. But it is not clear which structure you have and which result you want, it might be better to ask a new question.

Comment: `<root>
    <sibling1>
        <sibling2>
            <value1>somevalue</value1>
            <value2>somevalue</value2>
            <value3>somevalue</value3>
            <value4>somevalue</value4>
            <value5>Australia</value5>
            <value6>India</value6>
            <value7>USA</value7>
            <value8>somevalue</value8>
            <value9>somevalue</value9>
            <value10>somevalue</value10>
        </sibling2>
    </sibling1>
</root>` 
 
When i am using `<xsl:template match="/*"` It didn't group them country wise. It simply gives me my $doc

Comment: I think it is better to ask a new question with the [tag:xslt-2.0] and well-formatted input and output samples. I said you can use `match="/*"` if you want to "process the children of the root element", it seems your `valueX` elements are not children of the root element but of a `sibling2` element so you need to match on that. But it doesn't make much sense to exchange code in comments, ask a new question with formatted code samples in the question text and I am sure you will get an answer with formatted solutions in the answer text.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Posted a new question as suggested by you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52159957/how-to-wrap-the-elements-in-xslt-using-for-each-group

Comment: @MadsHansen-- Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 3):

For adjacent elements you could a `tumbling window` clause https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-31/#id-tumbling-windows:

```
declare variable $countries as xs:string* := ('Australia', 'India', 'USA');

<root>
{
    for tumbling window $w in root/*
    start $s when true()
    end next $n when ($s = $countries) and not($n = $countries) or (not($s = $countries) and $n = $countries)
    return 
        if ($w[1] = $countries)
        then <Country>
              {$w}
            </Country>
        else $w
}
</root>
```

https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWcDMeh/2

If you want to wrap based on element names then with a window clause you could use

```
declare variable $countries as xs:QName* := (QName('', 'value5'), QName('', 'value6'), QName('', 'value7'));

<root>
{
    for tumbling window $w in root/*
    start $s when true()
    end next $n 
       when ($s/node-name() = $countries) and not($n/node-name() = $countries)
            or (not($s/node-name() = $countries) and $n/node-name() = $countries)
    return 
        if ($s/node-name() = $countries)
        then <Country>
              {$w}
            </Country>
        else $w
}
</root>
```

https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWcDMeh/6

I have now also tried to avoid the use of the `window` clause and instead implement the wrapping with a recursive function:

```
declare variable $countries as xs:string* := ('Australia', 'India', 'USA');

declare function local:wrap($seq as item()*, $wrapper as element()) as item()*
{
  let $first-item := head($seq)
  return
    if (not($first-item))
    then (if (empty($wrapper/node())) then () else $wrapper)
    else if (not($first-item[. = $countries]))
    then 
      (if (empty($wrapper/node())) then () else $wrapper, 
       $first-item, 
       local:wrap(tail($seq), $wrapper!element {node-name()} {})
      )
    else local:wrap(tail($seq), $wrapper!element {node-name()} { node(), $first-item})
};

<root>
{
    local:wrap(root/*, <countries/>)
}
</root>
```

Seems to do the job as well at https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWcDMeh/4, I have no idea whether it makes sense with Marklogic. If you want to wrap based on the elements names and not values then you can adapt the code to https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWcDMeh/5 which declares

```
declare variable $countries as xs:QName* := (QName('', 'value5'), QName('', 'value6'), QName('', 'value7'));
```

and then compares `else if (not($first-item/node-name() = $countries))`.

If you only need to wrap all `value5`, `value6`, `value7` elements then I think you can simply use

```
/root/<root>
{
    let $values := (value5, value6, value7)
    return ( 
        * except $values, 
        if ($values) then <countries>{ $values }</countries> else ()
    )

}
</root>
```

https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWcDMeh/7

Comment: @Martin-- Thanks for answering. Your method looks advance to me. But when i am trying to run the same in MarkLogic's Query console-It gives me error for "tumbling window" as if it don't understands what is it. I am afraid if MarkLogic is yet to support the tumbling and sliding window concept as mentioned in the below post-https://developer.marklogic.com/pipermail/general/2015-January/016207.html

Comment: @Shalini, I hope someone with Marklogic expertise can help with a solution working there, I am sure the use case has in some way been implemented before.

Comment: @Martin-- Yes :) Thank you for introducing me to the concept of Tumbling and Sliding window. For me it's very new.

Comment: @Martin-- Thank you for giving me another approach. I will try to see if that helps.